# django makemigrations nomodule found error

Tags: django, django-models, makemigrations

I am trying to add models, but whenever I run python `manage.py makemigrations` I get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.staticfilesaccounts'
```

accounts is an app in my project, the structure of the files is as follows
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NWiZ.png)

The models file is,

```
from django.db import models

    # Create your models here.
    
    class Customer(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        phone=models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
        email=models.EmailField(max_length=20, null=True)
        dateCreated=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    class Product(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
        category=models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
        price=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

Im a Django beginner, could use some help. Much Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py` file, it should be like this:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    #...
]
```

Comment: yes the INSTALLED_APPS contains 'django.contrib.staticfiles' but I dont understand why django is looking for 'django.contrib.staticfilesaccounts'

Comment: Make sure that there is a comma after `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` app.